# Streaming a remote file in PHP is saving it to my server. Why?

Tags: php, fopen

I want just to stream the file, i don't want to save it on my ram or hdd. I am talking about streaming a hd video for each viewer individually.

There is my code:

```
// ...
ob_start();
header('...'); // I am sending some headers here
ob_flush(); flush(); ob_clean();

$handle = fopen('http://example.com/bigMovie.mp4', 'rb');
ob_flush(); flush(); ob_clean();
while(!feof($handle)) // do this until is the end of the file
{
    echo fread($handle, 102400); // reading 100 kb from file
    ob_flush(); flush(); ob_clean(); // sending it to the user, cleaning ram
}
ob_end_flush(); // finished sending the file
fclose($handle); // closing the remote connection to example.com
// ...
```

When I try to send **bigMovie.mp4** to a viewer my server's hdd gets full.

What whoud i do ? Is anything wrong with my code ?
Thanks.

Comment: your code makes no sense at all. please update your post with something that actually makes sense.

Comment: @LuckyBurger i have simplified everything. it makes sense now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
# Send headers
header('...');
header('...');
header('...');
...

# Send file
readfile('http://example.com/bigMovie.mp4');
```

`readfile()` reads a file (even remotely over http) and immediately outputs it's contents.

---

Btw, your usage of the `ob_*` functions makes no sense at all. You need to understand how output control works in php before using it. The manual is a good starting point: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: So you are getting the movie from a 3rd party site, loading it in your RAM, and then want to deliver it down to your users.  Are you loading it from your own CDN?  Most CDNs allow streaming of the files directly if you configure it to allow that.

Comment: `Most CDNs allow streaming of the files directly if you configure it to allow that.` Sounds like an interesting alternative. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I tried readfile and it did the same thing with my ob_* functions. Now looks like it's working fine. Thanks a lot. It was a stupid simple way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

@hek2mgl

Assuming these are your files that you are streaming to your users.  You can place the files in a CDN.  Here are a couple of the big players depending on your hosting preferences.

You can use Amazon Web Service's Cloudfront for streaming.
http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/

RackSpace CDN streaming
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/frequently-asked-question/getting-started-with-cloud-files-streaming

Azure CDN
http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/01/streaming-mp4-video-files-in-azure-storage-containers-blob-storage/